# Retrieving div "value" to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So, im trying to code a simple sliding puzzle and got really stuck.
I've got a 3x3 sqare with diffrent "values"

Now, im trying to move the number to the blank space and vice versa.

So my question is how can i, in the easiest possible manner, change my 'test' text to the value of the clicked div ?

All answers and tips are truely appreciated

-Karlsen

EDIT :

Added full code, its a bit more understanding now i think :

```js
          var counter = 0;
     var lastClickedDiv;


     function show(tag, alt1, alt2, alt3, alt4) {
       if (alt1 && document.getElementById(alt1).innerHTML == '') {
         document.getElementById(alt1).innerHTML = 'test';
         tag.innerHTML = '';
       }

       if (alt2 && document.getElementById(alt2).innerHTML == '') {
         document.getElementById(alt2).innerHTML = 'test1';
         tag.innerHTML = '';
       }

       if (alt3 && document.getElementById(alt3).innerHTML == '') {
         document.getElementById(alt3).innerHTML = 'test2';
         tag.innerHTML = '';
       }

       if (alt4 && document.getElementById(alt4).innerHTML == '') {
         document.getElementById(alt4).innerHTML = 'test3';
         tag.innerHTML = '';
       }
     }
```

```css
  div.container {
   display: flex;
   height: 28vh;
  }
   div.number {
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(140,0,0);
    margin: 10px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 500%;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
  <body>

   <H1> Sliding Puzzle </H1>

   <div class="container">
     <div id="a1" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a2', 'b1')">8</div>
     <div id="a2" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a1', 'a3', 'b2')">5</div>
     <div id="a3" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a2', 'b3')">4</div>
   </div>

   <div class="container">
     <div id="b1" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a1', 'b2', 'c1')">6</div>
     <div id="b2" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a2', 'b1', 'b3', 'c2')">7</div>
     <div id="b3" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a3', 'b2', 'c3')">2</div>
   </div>

   <div class="container">
     <div id="c1" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'b1', 'c2')">1</div>
     <div id="c2" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'c1', 'b2', 'c3')">3</div>
     <div id="c3" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'c2', 'b3')"></div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain more? What's desired output?

Comment: Desired output is document.getElementById(alt4).innerHTML = One of the DIV's that is clicked.. Hopefully that explains it well enough, english is not my first language and the lack of vocabulary makes it hard :)

Comment: In `show` function, alt4 will always come as undefined since your show function takes 5 parameters and you are passing at most 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you  want this, please try to run this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.container {
                display: flex;
                height: 28vh;
            }
            div.number {
                color:  black;
                background-color: rgb(140,0,0);
                margin: 10px;
                border: 10px solid black;
                display: flex;
                flex: 1;
                font-size: 500%;
                text-align: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1> Sliding Puzzle </H1>
        <div class="container">
            <div data-cell="0,0" class="number" >8</div>
            <div data-cell="0,1" class="number">5</div>
            <div data-cell="0,2" class="number">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div data-cell="1,0" class="number">6</div>
            <div data-cell="1,1" class="number">7</div>
            <div data-cell="1,2" class="number">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div data-cell="2,0" class="number">1</div>
            <div data-cell="2,1" class="number">3</div>
            <div data-cell="2,2" class="number"></div>
        </div>
        <script>

            //By defaul to null as we will calculate
            var emptyCell = null;
            var numbersEls = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
            for (var counter = 0, max = numbersEls.length; counter < max; counter++) {
                var el = numbersEls[counter];
                el.addEventListener('click', onNumberCellClick);
                if(el.innerHTML == ''){
                    emptyCell = el;             
                }
            }               

            function onNumberCellClick(clickedEl){
                var clickedEl = this;
                var cellIdentifier = getCellIdentifier(clickedEl);

                //if empty cell not null
                if(emptyCell){              

                    var swapPositions = getCellSwapAvailability(cellIdentifier);

                    //We can move the cell
                    if(swapPositions.indexOf(emptyCell.dataset.cell) > -1){
                        emptyCell.innerHTML = clickedEl.innerHTML;                  

                        //Swap the position as the empty cell is changed;
                        emptyCell = clickedEl;
                        emptyCell.innerHTML = '';
                    }
                }
            }

            function getCellSwapAvailability(identifier){
                //Calculate where cell can be moved
                var positions = [];
                var pos = identifier.row + ',' + (identifier.col-1);
                positions.push(pos);
                var pos = identifier.row + ',' + (identifier.col+1);
                positions.push(pos);
                var pos = (identifier.row-1) + ',' + (identifier.col);
                positions.push(pos);
                var pos = (identifier.row+1) + ',' + (identifier.col);
                positions.push(pos);
                return positions;
            }

            function getCellIdentifier(cell){
                var cellIndex = cell.dataset.cell;
                var identifierArr = cellIndex.split(',');
                var r = Number(identifierArr[0]);
                var c = Number(identifierArr[1]);
                return {row: r, col: c};
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Changed from jQuery to javascript

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for, thank you :) Ill use some time on understanding it now. Again, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, if you wish I can help you understand, I am there on skype

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: Actually, if you do have the time and energy, could you set up the "same" code just using javascript, not jQuery ? :)

Comment: @ThomasKarlsen please check, I have removed jquery

Comment: Thank you, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

First you have error in the javascript at line 4,

```
document.getElementById(alt1).innerHTML. = 'test';
```

there cannot be "." after innerHTML.

May be that is the problem and you not able to run your JS

Comment: Ah, that was a sneaky one that came by when i copy pasted the code. But quite observant! :-)

Comment: I tried to execute your code which gave me error. All thanks to chrome debugger. Were you able to solve the issue? Please mark it as answer if it did. thanks

Comment: I was not able to solve the problem yet. This is also just a part of the code, if you want the full thing just say so, ill post it :)

Comment: If you wish, then go ahead, I will see what I can do for it

Comment: The full code is now in the original post. Thank you so much DASH :)

Comment: I have added another answer, please try to look into it. I have used jQuery in that, if you want we can do it with normal javascript also. I find jquery quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra "." as @DASH suggested at line 4 in javascript, and you have a missing **<kbd>'</kbd>** at line 4 in in the HTML.

I added a bit of CSS to see better if you don't mind.

```js
function show(tag, alt1, alt2, alt3, alt4) {
  if (alt1 && document.getElementById(alt1).innerHTML == '') {
    document.getElementById(alt1).innerHTML = 'test';
    tag.innerHTML = '';
  }

  if (alt2 && document.getElementById(alt2).innerHTML == '') {
    document.getElementById(alt2).innerHTML = 'test1';
    tag.innerHTML = '';
  }

  if (alt3 && document.getElementById(alt3).innerHTML == '') {
    document.getElementById(alt3).innerHTML = 'test2';
    tag.innerHTML = '';
  }

  if (alt4 && document.getElementById(alt4).innerHTML == '') {
    document.getElementById(alt4).innerHTML = 'test3';
    tag.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: beige;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.number {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="a1" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a2', 'b1')">8</div>
  <div id="a2" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a1', 'a3', 'b2')">5</div>
  <div id="a3" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a2', 'b3')">4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="b1" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a1', 'b2', 'c1')">6</div>
  <div id="b2" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a2', 'b1', 'b3', 'c2')">7</div>
  <div id="b3" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'a3', 'b2', 'c3')">2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="c1" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'b1', 'c2')">1</div>
  <div id="c2" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'c1', 'b2', 'c3')">3</div>
  <div id="c3" class="number" onclick="show(this, 'c2', 'b3')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, got that part figured out now. Now, the next part is keeping the numbers, not having the "test" text. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Please elaborate, so that I can assist your for that

Comment: do you want to move numbers to empty box if there is any empty box next to them?

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do!